# Challenging problem: How to find near duplicates for string?

Tags: string, duplicates, stanford-nlp, string-comparison, difflib

I have a dataset that consists of over 50000 names. There are a lot of near duplicates inside because of how these names were entered into the system.

The ideal solution should flag clusters of similar names for consideration for merging as they belong to the same person OR make constructive steps towards uncovering duplicates.

Suppose that these 6 persons are listed in a variety of ways in the 30 names in the second list:

1. Jon Stewart
2. Sun Yat-Sen
3. Xi Jinping
4. Jawaharlal Nehru
5. Hồ Chí Minh
6. Elaine Chao

30 Variations of 6 Names

1. Jon Stewart
2. John Stuart
3. Stewart Jon
4. Jonathon Stuart Leibowitz
5. Jon Stewart Jr
6. Stuart Leibowitz Jr
7. Sun Yat Sen
8. Sun Yat-Sen
9. Sun Sen Yat
10. Sun Sun-Yat
11. Sen Yat-Sun
12. Xi Jinping
13. Xi Jin Ping
14. Xi Jing Pin
15. Xin Ji Ping
16. Jawaharlal Nehru
17. Jawa Haral Nehru
18. Jawaharul Neru
19. Jawaha Rul Naru
20. Ho Chi Minh
21. Hồ Chí Minh
22. Ho Chimin
23. Ho Chimminh
24. Elaine Chao
25. Chao Xiao Lan Elaine
26. Xiao Lan, Elaine Chao
27. Xiao Chao Lan, Elaine
28. Chao Xiao Elaine
29. Elaine Xiao Lan Chao
30. Ellaine Chao Xiao-Lan

How do I start cleaning this dataset so that I can "flag" up all these names to take a closer look to make data cleaning decisions?

I have implemented methods that used Levenshtein Distance, but they do not do well with strings of very different lengths. Most people have 3 (plus minus 1) names. Some names are hyphenated.

I have situations where the same persons have been entered very differently like #1 and #2 where there are no overlaps in terms of spellings, but their reference to the same person can be inferred / triangulated through other entries and information in other columns. I acknowledge that there are limitations in finding a solution, as it may require some triangulation of different cells. For instance, Asians often have multiple names and people are often unsure which is which, and they often choose some parts of name to input. I am happy work with solutions that can partially tackle some but not all of the problems.

My estimate of the number of unique individuals in this 50000 is about 20000 or so. These are individuals providing professional services in a geographical location, in which I can in a somewhat laborious way, check against that database as a last resort (as that database does not allow any sort of automated querying).

Comment: To be clear: all these names refer to only one person, this person's full name is Gregory John Adam Floyd Jr, and they go by any arbitrary combination? So Gregory John is the same person as Adam Floyd?

Comment: How many different persons do these 50000 names correspond too? I expect a system to flag near duplicates would too easily find false positives, especially with common names such as Lee or John.

Comment: @Stef to your question, I have situations like this in my dataset, but acknowledge that there are limitations in finding a solution, as it may require some triangulation of different cells.  For example, Asian names have multiple words and people are often unsure which is which, and they often choose some parts of name to input. I am happy work with solutions that can partially tackle some but not all of the problems.

Comment: @Stef My estimates of number of unique individuals in this 50000 is about 20000 or so. These are individuals providing professional services in a geographical location, in which I can in a somewhat laborious way, check against that database as a last resort (as that database does not allow any sort of automated querying).

Comment: So you have an average of 2.5 names per person. Do you know whether most persons have two names, or whether most persons have one name but a minority of persons have lots of names?

Comment: Most people have 3 or so names. Some names are hyphenated.

Comment: That's very relevant information. I suggest editing the question post to include it. Maybe also include an example with 25 names corresponding to a total of 10 people. Including such an example might help a lot, as people who have ideas about these kinds of problems can more easily see whether their ideas would be suitable or not given this example.

Answer (score 1):

I created a tool years ago to do the same with streets. In case it gives you a direction, I used difflib:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html

My approach was:

- To create a list with the standard names I wanted to use and replace names when the matching score was very high.
- For those with a lesser score and did some checking loops to show me the 2-3 closest matches.
- After checking several dozens, I did some cleanse with `replace` over the typical results not providing good scores and start again with the `SequenceMatcher`.

An example of the sorted result:

```
result=sorted(b, key=lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, c).ratio(), reverse=True)
```

**UPDATE:**
I've done two examples, the first to create a new_agenda based on the matching results. The second an example to let you see the scores:

```
import difflib

#Your list of names (the six provided)
clean_agenda=['Jon Stewart','Sun Yat-Sen','Xi Jinping','Jawaharlal Nehru','Hồ Chí Minh','Elaine Chao']

#Your agenda with any kind of names (the fifty provided)
agenda=['Jon Stewart','John Stuart','Stewart Jon','Jonathon Stuart Leibowitz','Jon Stewart Jr','Stuart Leibowitz Jr','Sun Yat Sen','Sun Yat-Sen','Sun Sen Yat','Sun Sun-Yat','Sen Yat-Sun','Xi Jinping','Xi Jin Ping','Xi Jing Pin','Xin Ji Ping','Jawaharlal Nehru','Jawa Haral Nehru','Jawaharul Neru','Jawaha Rul Naru','Ho Chi Minh','H? Chí Minh','Ho Chimin','Ho Chimminh','Elaine Chao','Chao Xiao Lan Elaine','Xiao Lan, Elaine Chao','Xiao Chao Lan, Elaine','Chao Xiao Elaine','Elaine Xiao Lan Chao','Ellaine Chao Xiao-Lan']

#Your new agenda to store your matching clean names
new_agenda=[]

# Creating a new agenda with your standard list of names
for i in range(len(agenda)):
    resultado=sorted(clean_agenda, key=lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, agenda[i]).ratio(), reverse=True)
    new_agenda.append(resultado[0])
```

The example to see the ratios:

```
# An example of a loop to check ratios for each value in agenda
for i in range(len(agenda)):
    for j in range(len(clean_agenda)):
        print(clean_agenda[j], difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,agenda[i],clean_agenda[j]).ratio())
    print('\n')
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. What if I do not have a list of standard names? Perhaps I can theoretically use 10% of the unique values (at each time) as "standard" to run what you suggested and loop this iteratively? Do you have a worked example from your own work? I am very noob in this.

Comment: thanks much for this. I will definitely try it out and let you now how it pans out. Grateful.

Comment: How do you interpret these?
Jon Stewart 1.0
Sun Yat-Sen 0.36363636363636365
Xi Jinping 0.19047619047619047
Jawaharlal Nehru 0.2962962962962963
Hồ Chí Minh 0.09090909090909091
Elaine Chao 0.09090909090909091

Jon Stewart 0.8181818181818182
Sun Yat-Sen 0.2727272727272727
Xi Jinping 0.19047619047619047
Jawaharlal Nehru 0.2962962962962963
Hồ Chí Minh 0.18181818181818182
Elaine Chao 0.09090909090909091

Comment: 1.0 is a perfect match (all characters match, position an d number). Play with the code and read library docs and other questions to know more about it.